# Deploying an add-in for Office 2003 and Office 2007 (with Ribbon support)

Tags: ms-office, ribbon, office-interop, office-2007, office-2010

I wrote a Word 2003 add-in that uses the 2003 PIAs for early-binding. I want the same executable to support the Ribbon interface in Office 2007 and 2010, while still running in Office 2003.

Is it possible to late-bind the IRibbonExtensibility interface? If not, is there another way to dynamically differentiate between Office versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good book on working with the ribbon UI in Office:
RibbonX: Customizing the Office 2007 Ribbon
Robert Martin, Ken Puls, Teresa Hennig

The authors and MS both suggest a trick along these lines for solving this problem:

When your add-in loads, it queries the app to find out what version it's running in.

If Office 2003, it creates a normal CommandBars 'n Buttons UI.

If Office 2007 or later, it looks for another add-in and demand-loads it.  This second add-in contains just the RibbonX code to create your ribbon UI plus handlers for the button click events.  The handler simply calls back to the main add-in.

With a little clever use of tags in your RibbonXML and handler, you can have a single handler work out which routine in the main add-in to call.